# Getting error in finding out Recency in Bigquery(SQL)? (RFM Analysis)

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-science, data-analysis

I am writing a Google Bigquery for doing RFM analysis by using following sql queries but getting errors. Unable to calculate the Recency and Bigquery is not recognizing Day in DAY_DFF Function.
Your help will be appreciated!

```sql
    -- Customer_ID = vstr_id, Order_ID = vst_id, Order_Date = evnt_dt, Sales = tot_sale_amt
    --STEP 1: FILTER THE DATASET
    WITH dataset AS (
        SELECT vstr_id, 
               vst_id, 
               evnt_dt, 
               tot_sale_amt
        FROM item_purchase
        WHERE evnt_dt < CURRENT_DATE - 17
    ),

    -- STEP 3: SUMMARIZE THE DATASET

    Order_Summary as (
        SELECT vstr_id, vst_id, evnt_dt,
            SUM(tot_sale_amt) as tot_sale_amt
        FROM dataset
        GROUP BY vstr_id, vst_id, evnt_dt
    )

    -- Step 4: Put together the RFM Report

    SELECT 
    t1.vstr_id,
    --(SELECT MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary) as max_order_date,
    --(SELECT MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary) WHERE vstr_id = t1.vstr_id) as max_customer_order_date
    -- Now we want to substract max_customer_order_date from max_order_date.
    DATE_DIFF(day, (SELECT MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary WHERE vstr_id = t1.vstr_id), (SELECT 
    MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary)) as Recency,

    COUNT(t1.vst_id) as Frequency,
    SUM(t1.tot_sale_amt) as Monetary
    FROM Order_Summary t1
    GROUP BY t1.vstr_id
    ORDER BY 1,3 DESC
```

Comment: Second argument of **DATE_DIFF** in your query seems not a **DATE** type.  It shoud be like **DATE_DIFF('2022-07-12, '2022-07-11, DAY)**.  3rd argument should mostly be **DAY** literal but a **DATE(evnt_dt)** in your query.

Comment: @Jaytiger I have edited my query. Can you post the part of your query where i need to change it.

Comment: kindly check my comment in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your **Recency** part should be like:

```sql
DATE_DIFF(
  (SELECT MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary), -- last event day of all
  (SELECT MAX(evnt_dt) FROM Order_Summary WHERE vstr_id = t1.vstr_id), -- last event day of each visitor.
  DAY
) AS Recency,
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff